# How can I get pytest to respect test_suite() when it's defined?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to get tests for [testfixtures](https://github.com/Simplistix/testfixtures) passing with pytest but some of the test modules use the [old pattern](https://github.com/Simplistix/testfixtures/blob/master/testfixtures/tests/test_logcapture.py#L380) of defining a function called test_suite that returns the tests:

```
def test_suite():
    return TestSuite((
        DocTestSuite(setUp=setUp, tearDown=tearDown),
        makeSuite(LogCaptureTests),
        ))
```

When pytest tries to collect this, it fails and complains:

```
WC1 /Users/chris/vcs/git/testfixtures/testfixtures/tests/test_logcapture.py cannot collect test class 'TestSuite' because it has a __init__ constructor
```

How can I get it to collect the tests instead?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem possible with pytest.

When asked (in [issue 1877](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1877) the project's response was that "by design we do not expose unittest suites".

Comment: Yeah, pytest support for things like Sybil and Manuel actually ends up being pretty painful: https://github.com/simplistix/sybil/blob/master/sybil/integration/pytest.py

If this is for Manuel, you could give Sybil a spin and save yourself a maintenance burned ;-) https://sybil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  That implementation does look painful.  : )